# Everything is correct but codeigniter showing Message: Undefined variable: data

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please read the code below

Insertmodel.php

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Insertmodel extends CI_Model {

    public function insertdata($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('page',$data);
    }
    public function getpagedata()
    {
        //$this->db->select('pname,purl,pub');
        //$this->db->from('page');
        //$this->load->database();

        $getquery = $this->db->get('page');
        return $getquery->result();
    }
}
```

Pagedatainsert.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pagedatainsert extends CI_Controller {

    public function insertdata()
    {
        $this->load->helper('date');
        $this->load->model('insertmodel','tblselect');
        $data = array(
            'pname'=>$this->input->post('page-name'),
            'purl'=>$this->input->post('page-url'),
            'pcon'=>$this->input->post('page-content'),
            'pub'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
        $this->tblselect->insertdata($data);
    }
    public function gpdatacon()
    {
        $this->load->model('insertmodel');
        $data['query'] = $this->insertmodel->getpagedata();
        $this->load->view('backend/pages/pages',$data);
    }
}
```

pages.php (which is under directory backend/pages)

```
<?php foreach($data as $row){?>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td><?= $row->pname; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->purl; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->pub; ?></td>
</tr>    
<?php } ?>
```

Here an error is occurred which says

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: data
Filename: pages/pages.php
Line Number: 73
Backtrace:
File: D:\Ampps\www\customcms\application\views\backend\pages\pages.php
Line: 73
Function: _error_handler
File: D:\Ampps\www\customcms\application\controllers\Backmanage.php
Line: 26
Function: view
File: D:\Ampps\www\customcms\index.php
Line: 316
Function: require_once
```

My database name is `customcms`, table name is `page`.

Made lots of searching on google already but not found so much. Besides, I found a question like this on stackoverflow but that was not so much helpful in my case. I am working for entire day on this problem but it is not getting resolved.

Comment: I also tried foreach($query as $row) instead of foreach($data as $row) in view but not working still.

Comment: Error is about `Backmanage.php` controller file. You didn't show that one nor show us URL that you are trying to access along with routes.php file code.

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'backmanage';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: I have also tried to pass simple values directly from the controller. I changed $data['query'] to $data = "hello" and tried to echo it on the view but it shows nothing. After tried echo var_dump($data); shown NULL. Its not sending data from controller to the view.

Comment: Show us `Backmanage.php` controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it myself that was the issue with the URL I was calling. I made two pages similar in looks. and accidentally calling the wrong URL that was obvious not working.

Answer (score 3):

Change it:

```
$this->load->view('backend/pages/pages',$data);
```

to

```
$this->load->view('backend/pages/pages',array('data' => $data));
```

or change it:

```
<?php foreach($data as $row){?>
```

to

```
<?php foreach($query as $row){?>
```

**Explanation:** The second parameter of `view()` function is an array like

```
view('viewname', array('data' => $data))
```

and on view you can access it by using `$data`. If you pass `$data` then you have to use by its index i.e. `$query`

Answer (score 1):

change $data to `$query` cause you store all data in `$data['query']` so you get all data in $qyery variable

```
<?php foreach($data as $row){?>
.............  
<?php } ?>
```

to

```
<?php foreach($query as $row){?>
............   
<?php } ?>
```

if not work then print_r use and check that value exit

```
 public function gpdatacon()
    {
        $this->load->model('insertmodel');
        $data['query'] = $this->insertmodel->getpagedata();
        print_r( $data['query']);
        die()
        $this->load->view('backend/pages/pages',$data);
    }
```

for more information

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: thanks for the answer but I already tried putting $query in foreach as per my earlier comment above